# Function pointer as a template

Tags: c++

How to write a function pointer as template?

```
template <typename T>
T (*PtrToFunction)(T a);
```

Comment: That would amount to a "template typedef", which doesn't exist. In C++11 you have template aliases, but I'm not sure if they cover that situation.

Comment: If your application's size warrants it, use a more general functor object like [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/function.html) which allows you to use any kind of callable object, not just function pointers. If you're writing a small app, don't bother.

Answer (score 8):

I am assuming you are trying to declare a type (you cannot declare a "template variable" without a concrete type).

C++03 doesn't have template typedefs, you need to use a struct as a workaround:

```
template <typename T>
struct FuncPtr {
    typedef T (*Type)(T a);
};

...

// Use template directly
FuncPtr<int>::Type intf;

// Hide behind a typedef
typedef FuncPtr<double>::Type DoubleFn;
DoubleFn doublef;
```

C++11 template aliases will eliminate the struct workaround, but presently no compilers except [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) actually implement this.

```
template <typename T>
typedef T (*FuncPtr)(T a);

// Use template directly
FuncPtr<int> intf;

// Hide behind a typedef
typedef FuncPtr<double> DoubleFn;
DoubleFn doublef;
```

Comment: Just updating this old entry to mention that as of GCC 4.7, GCC now supports template aliases.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean create a type for that function, you could do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Function {
    typedef T (*Ptr)(T);
};
```

Then use it like

```
int blah(Function<int>::Ptr a) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. You can only create function pointers with concrete type.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok on Visual Studio 2015 and on GCC you should use command line option `-std=c++11`

```
template<class T> using fpMember = void (T::*)();
```