# function ptr to a function with template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

how would i define a function ptr which points to a function which gives back a boolean but takes two unknown (but equal) types as arguments?

Should be something like this, but my IDE marks this as wrong:

`template<class arg>

bool (ptr*)(arg,arg);`

I also want to combine this with a function which takes such a function-ptr to compare two arguments it gets.

like:

`template<class arg>

void function(arg one,arg two,ptr comparefunction)`

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293640/function-pointer-as-a-template/7293669#7293669

Comment: I approve of your spelling.  But you should be konsistent about it in your spelling of 'kombine'. (aww man. awoodland ruined it)

Comment: That would make a kool band name. Oh wait, it IS a band name.

Comment: How is this question different than the one linked as a duplicate? Voting to close.

Comment: @Emile - If the intended use age is just to use it within a template context like `function` then the solution is quite different to the workarounds proposed to get template typedef like behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have template typedefs, which seems to be what you're asking about initially. For the function which takes a function pointer you can do:

```
template<class arg>
void function(arg one,arg two,bool (*comparefunction)(arg,arg))
```

instead.

Your initial syntax is also wrong:

```
bool (*ptr)(arg,arg); // * goes before the name
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is possible, in this way:

```
template<class TArg>
struct funptr
{
  typedef bool (type*)(TArg, TArg);
};

template<class TArg>
void function(TArg one,TArg two,typename funptr<TArg>::type compare)
{
}
```

Or, simply do this:

```
template<class TArg>
void function(TArg one, TArg two, bool (*compare)(TArg, TArg) )
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like in the other question, you must use a `struct`:

```
template<typename T>
struct Function {
    typedef bool (*Ptr)(T, T);
};
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
Function<int>::Ptr f = &myfunction;
```

As for the second one, you can do this:

```
template<class T>
void function(T one, T two, typename Function<T>::Ptr comparefunction)
```